# PyCharm linter not resolving all PyQt5 import references properly

Tags: python, pycharm, pyqt5

An extremely minor problem, but an annoying one all the same- as you can see in the picture below, some references are resolved correctly by the linter (like pyqtSignal and pyqtSlot), and some are not (pyqtProperty).

[image: PyCharm can find pyqtSignal and pyqtSlot, but not pyqtProperty?]

What's even weirder is that code using these 'unresolved' references run just fine, it's just the linter/syntax highlighter that can't seem to find this reference.

Software used:

- PyCharm 2017.3 (but this also happened on PyCharm 2017.2.X as well)
- Python 3.6.3
- PyQt 5.6.0, Qt 5.6.2
- Windows 10 Pro x64

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to install these packages on my machine in order to check, but this likely isn't an issue with PyCharm.

Try `Ctrl+Click` on `QtCore`. I'm guessing this will take you to a file. Is `pyqtProperty` in that file? I'm guessing not. However, I'm guessing `pyqtSignal` and `pyqtSlot` are.

A couple reasons come to mind for why this might be happening

1. `pyqtProperty` is not supported with version 5.6.0 and you need to install a different version
2. The the Python interpreter which you are using does not actually have the version installed which you think
3. Is PyQt a python wrapper around a c++ package? I've seen it before where essentially the package was made wrong and the calls still went to c++ correctly, but they did not add in the Python object declarations correctly such that IDEs recognized them and a bug needed to be placed on the package's github.

Comment: I'm using 5.10.1 and it is definitely there. The REPL has no problem accessing it. PyCharm does have a problem. I can see the symbol for it in QtCore.so. QtCore.py doesn't have it.